# Can I create a datagrid which different row contain different type of control in same column in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

For easiest case: datagrid with 5 cols, 2 rows, don't care about 4 first cols, in 5th col:

1st row: it's a textbox
2nd row: it's a combobox.

Comment: For now, there's no such API for you to do it. Please submit a **Feature Request** on [WindowsCommunityToolkit Issues](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22feature+request%22).

Comment: I've helped you submit a 'Feature Request' on github(https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2958).